# Restrict Multiple Login of same user across 2 Web Applications

Tags: servlets, architecture, websphere, httpsession, tomcat9

We have got requirement to restrict concurrent login of same user across 2 Web Applications.

We have 2 Web Applications for example: WebApp1, WebApp2.

User: Dashboard

If Dashboard user is logged into WebApp1 then the same user is not allowed to login to WebApp2 instead show error message on second login.

Tried Solution:

Block 2nd login with same user id if there is an active session and show error message to user.

The idea is to maintain user id, Application Name and session id in DB. On second login of same user check if record exist in DB table against the user id then block 2nd login and show error message to user.

Clear the DB record (UserId, Session Id, and Application Name) in following 
scenarios:

1. Logout
2. Session Timeout
3. Restart of Application.

Not Sure how to handle below scenarios.

4. Close Browser.
5. Browser Crash
6. System Crash

If 2nd login request is from valid user then Admin should able to Invalidate the session of first login as this user is attacker.

what is best way to invalidate Http session of WebApp2/ WebApp1?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to know the state of the first session, I would skip trying to manage sessions in the server, and instead maintain a heartbeat from the client.  Have the client make a request every 5 seconds to the server which updates a "Last Seen" record, which includes their IP address and which app they are from, and whether "Last Seen" was a logout event.

Then the other app can interrogate "Last Seen", and if it's more than 5 seconds (I'd actually bump it to 10 for the interrogation), or a LogOut event, assume that the first session went away, and that they are free to log into the second application.  If "Last Seen" is less than 5-10 seconds, bump them both out and alert the admin with both the IP Addresses to decide which one should be killed.

Comment: This would be overkill. Imagine you have 1k users, this would give you 200 useless requests per sec. And you would also disable effectively session inactivity timeout, as UI would constantly generate new requests.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you have, you could save last activity time in your session DB, and update it, when there is a session update, how often ( every request or once in 5 min for example) it depends on your requirements. Then in case of app/browser/system restart, you log in user, even if record exist, if it is older that session timeout. And you can have admin user that can manually delete entry if required.

The other solution would be to always log in new app, and logout the old one. But that would require introducing additional logic in the application to check if session is still valid.

Comment: Thanks for Response. To logout old one: having 2 Web Applications not sure how do we get HttpSession of Other web application. For example: Dashboard user logged into WebApp1 and 2nd login of same user in WebApp2. I think may need to look at writing code at Container level - for example : Tomcat -Valve.

Comment: Thats why, I wrote it needs additional logic, could be runtime dependent. Of course you could write something simple (but maybe not the best from the performance/efficiency) like servlet filter, which would check the DB if the session is still valid, if not, do the auto logout in the container.